# HTML/CSS - Gap between text in table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm creating HTML newsletter, so tables would be they way to go. However I'm facing issue with gaps, when there is small amount of text in table cells. How it can be fixed?

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/gakaLpqn/

```
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 350px">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 18px; padding-right: 20px" text="#000"><img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="170" height="170"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px" text="#000">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 18px;" text="#000">When there is a small amount of text, the gap will be bigger. <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 350px">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 18px; padding-right: 20px" text="#000"><img src="http://placehold.it/170"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px" text="#000">Vestibulum nec viverra nisi. Sed aliquet urna facilisis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 18px;" text="#000">Fusce nibh lorem, condimentum vitae maximus eget, vestibulum et nisl. Mauris neque massa, imperdiet vitae finibus vel, maximus nec quam. </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your issue? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You could change de markup like this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/gakaLpqn/2/)**

```html
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 350px">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right: 20px">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="170" height="170" />
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"> 
            <div style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px" text="#000">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
            <div style="font-weight: normal; line-height: 18px;" text="#000">When there is a small amount of text, the gap will be bigger.</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 350px">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right: 20px">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/170" />
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;line-height: 18px;">
            <div style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 20px">Vestibulum nec viverra nisi. Sed aliquet urna facilisis</div>
            <div style="font-weight: normal;">Fusce nibh lorem, condimentum vitae maximus eget, vestibulum et nisl. Mauris neque massa, imperdiet vitae finibus vel, maximus nec quam.</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

I simplified the markup and the styles too.

Answer (score 0):

If your titles have consistent length you could use a fixed height for the title row and remove the padding, so in every case your body text will be right under the title.

Answer (score 0):

You did encapsulate the tr and td in wrong way. Maybe try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gakaLpqn/3/

```
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 350px">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 18px; padding-right: 20px" text="#000"><img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="170" height="170"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px" text="#000"><div style="font-weight:bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
           <div >When there is a small amount of text, the gap will be bigger. <br></div>
                </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 350px">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 18px; padding-right: 20px" text="#000"><img src="http://placehold.it/170"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px" text="#000"><div style="font-weight:bold">Vestibulum nec viverra nisi. Sed aliquet urna facilisis</div>
            <div > Fusce nibh lorem, condimentum vitae maximus eget, vestibulum et nisl. Mauris neque massa, imperdiet vitae finibus vel, maximus nec quam.</div >
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```